# Html.SelectFor razor syntax add class

Tags: asp.net, css, razor

I want to add a class to a selectfor

but I get an error

```
@Html.SelectFor(m => m.foo, optionLabel: null, new { @class = "foo12" })
```

With a text box it works:

```
@Html.TextBoxFormattedFor(m => m.foo, new { @class = "foo" })
```

Error I get:

> Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified.

Comment: Error I get:

Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory -- any named arguments (in this case "optionLabel") have to come after unnamed ones.  So instead of this:

```
@Html.SelectFor(m => m.foo,      // 1
    optionLabel: null,           // 2
    new { @class = "foo12" }     // 3
)
```

I guess you probably want this:

```
@Html.SelectFor(m => m.foo,                      // 1
    optionLabel: null,                           // 2
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "foo12" }     // 3
)
```

**Edit**

Surely you mean [`DropDownListFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703567%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), and not "SelectListFor"?  You need to provide the options as well.  Something like this:

```
@{ 
    var selectList = new SelectListItem[] 
    { 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "text", Value = "value" },
    };
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.foo, 
    selectlist: selectlist,
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "foo" }
)
```

Comment: Yep this worked, figured out just before I checked back to the thread.

Thanks

 @Html.SelectFor(m => m.foo, optionLabel: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "foo" })